# Understanding proof of Collins' Weingarten calculus formula

Tags: probability, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, unitary-matrices

I am trying to understand Collins' paper on Weingarten calculus. You can find it here: [click!](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0205010)

On page 7, between the formulas $(2.6)$ and $(2.7)$, he claims that the action $\pi^{\otimes q} \otimes \Psi$ is on $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$, but, as far as I understand, since both $\pi^{\otimes q}$ and $\Psi$ are on  $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$, the tensor product action should be on $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q} \otimes M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$, right? However, the minimal invariant projections $I_\lambda$ are multiplicated by a $\tilde{B}$, which is an element of $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$, confirming that the afore-mentioned action should be on $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$. Am I missing something?

Moreover, he claims that we know, from representation theory, that an algebra is abelian and that the minimal invariant projections are indexed by partitions of $q$. Could you provide me with a reference on that? I would be very interested by a reference carrying out concrete examples for small $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, sure, *technically* putting a $\otimes$ symbol between $\pi^{\otimes q}$ and $\Psi$ ought to imply an action on the tensor product $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}\otimes M_d(\mathbb{Q})^{\otimes q}$, but that's not what they mean. Since the action of $\Psi$ normalizes the action of $\mathbb{U}_d^q$ (adopting their notation of $\mathbb{U}_d$), so there is an action of the semidirect product $\mathbb{U}_d^q\rtimes S_q$, which is known as the wreath product $\mathbb{U}_d\wr S_d$, on $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. Maybe you want to say $\pi^{\otimes q}\cdot\Psi$ instead of $\pi^{\otimes q}\otimes\Psi$.

The keyword to start searching is "Schur-Weyl duality."

Comment: I'm not sure it's $\mathbb{U}^q_d$! I think its the same unitary $U$ that is supposed to act on each factor of the tensor product $M_d(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes q}$. And what do you mean by "normalize"? Acting by $\sigma$, then $U$, then by $\sigma^{-1}$ is like acting by some other $U'$ (a subgroup $H$ normalizes a subgroup $K$ if $\forall h\in H,\ k \in K,\quad h^{-1}kh \in K$, right?)?

Comment: @Plop Well, there is an action with $\Bbb U_d^q$, but it seems that they are restricting to the diagonal copy of $\Bbb U_d$ within $\Bbb U_d^q$, yes.

Comment: Ok! I've seen plenty of litterature on Schur-Weyl duality, can you provide me with a precise reference? And what about the normalization of the action?

Comment: Moreover, the author writes $\mathbb{U}_d \times \mathcal{S}_d$ so maybe the two actions just commute...

Comment: Oh, I guess they commute: $\Psi$ just acts by permuting the factors of the tensor product, and $\pi$ acts factorwise!